# How to hyperlink an array of text using URLs in the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Spreadsheet I have a column of data with book titles, and a column data with of URLS in it, about 5000 rows. I would like to use appscript to make a new column of data with those same titles hyperlinked using the URLS in the other column.

I'm trying to do this with arrays and the map function but I'm not sure how to use the map function so that the titles become hyperlinked. I'm very new at this so need a bit of help. Here's what I'm doing so far, the "????" in the MakeURL function is placeholder for the fix.  Any suggestions?

Thank you for helping!

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet=ss.getActiveSheet();

function mainfunction() {
//Get both non-contiguous values into separate arrays.
  var titles = activeSheet.getRange('E:E').getValues();
  var theURLS = activeSheet.getRange('Q:Q').getValues();

//Put both values into a single unified array
  var unified=[];
  for (var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
    unified.push(titles[i],theURLS[i])
  }


//Run a transformation on the values of the unified array and output it into newTitles array
  var newtitles = unified.map(makeURL);

//write the new hyperlinked titles into a range(column).
activeSheet.getRange('Z:Z').setValues(newtitles);
};

  function makeURL(row){ return ?????; };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "E" and "Q".

  - The columns "E" and "Q" are the title and the hyperlink, respectively.
- You want to create the hyperlink value using the title and hyperlink, and want to put the values to the column "Z".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to use RichTextValues. When this is reflected to your script, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

When you run the function of the modified `mainfunction`, the hyperlink values created from the columns "E" and "Q" are put to the column "Z".

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function mainfunction() {
  //Get both non-contiguous values into separate arrays.
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var titles = activeSheet.getRange('E1:E' + lastRow).getValues();
  var theURLS = activeSheet.getRange('Q1:Q' + lastRow).getValues();

  var richTextValues = titles.map(([e], i) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e).setLinkUrl(theURLS[i][0]).build()]);
  activeSheet.getRange('Z1:Z' + richTextValues.length).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- If you will achieve your goal using the built-in formula, I thought that you can also use the following formula. In this case, please put it to the cell "Z1".

  ```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(Q:Q,E:E))
  ```
- If you want to put the formulas using Google Apps Script, I thought that you can also use the following script.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    function mainfunction() {
      //Get both non-contiguous values into separate arrays.
      var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
      var titles = activeSheet.getRange('E1:E' + lastRow).getValues();
      var theURLS = activeSheet.getRange('Q1:Q' + lastRow).getValues();

      var formulas = titles.map(([e], i) => [`HYPERLINK("${theURLS[i][0]}","${e}")`]);
      activeSheet.getRange('Z1:Z' + formulas.length).setFormulas(formulas);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValues(RichTextValue))